# VS2010 Professional - Debugging very slow in just Web code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have VS2010 Professional edition and I recently started getting problems debugging an MVC website. The debugging at the Controller code is very slow and each F10 command takes 20 seconds to move to the next line.
Javascript code debugging is quick. I tried a console app and a Forms app and debugging is quick. I also tried creating a blank new MVC app website and the debugger slows down. I am using IIS7.0. This recently started happening as I recently installed VS2012 Ultimate RC. I thought it may be the reason and uninstalled all the software VS2012RC Ultimate installed on that day and the debugger retuned to normal. Looking at task manager devenv.exe was using about 1GB of memory and w3wp.exe was also consuming memory and increasing to 800MB. Has anyone recently installed VS2012 RC Ultimate alongside VS2012 Professional and got into similar problems? Does any one who what is the rootcause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting IntelliTrace to collect events only in Options -> IntelliTrace -> General. This might speed up debugging.

Comment: VS2010 Professional does not get intellitrace out of the box

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I use Ultimate so I didn't consider that. Anyway, it also helps when you delete all your breakpoints (Ctrl-Shift-F9) and then set the ones you need manually. Note that this only works when you hit "delete all breakpoints", removing them manually one by one won't help. If that doesn't make any difference you can try deleting the .suo file in your project, though your project settings will be lost in that case.